# SonarQube: replacement for deprecated language analysis parameter

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) of SonarQube, the `sonar.language` parameter that used to set the language on which to perform the analysis is now deprecated;

Is there an alternative for this?
How SonarQube scanning process now sets the default language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language is determined by file extension. You don't need to set the language explicitly for the analysis

Comment: so if there are mixed languages (e.g. `.py`, `.js`) it will automatically detect them and apply the appropriate rules?

Comment: yes, language is detected and then analyzed with the rules from corresponding plugin

Comment: Yes, but when you have to have the ability to scan both VB and VB.NET projects this causes the inability to scan either.  We cannot eliminate the ability to scan VB projects at the server level, and we used to specifically provide the "/d:sonar.language=vbnet"
  for VB.Net projects.  how can we tell the scanner "This is a VB.NET project" not a "VB" project so it will scan?

Comment: @JaedenRuiner please ask your question on https://community.sonarsource.com/